# Angular Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: javascript, angular, cors, preflight

I'm having problem with https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/en/ace/pronunciations API I have used this code on other API's.
I tried to use POSTMAN and its working. So I think the problem is on my code.

```
getWord(word) {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Accept','application/json');
  headers.append('app_id','xxxxxx');
  headers.append('app_key','xxxxx');

  return this._http.get('https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/en/ace/pronunciations',{headers:headers})
     .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Notice the part of the error message that says:

```
The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

That indicates an authentication failure.

So that probably just means you’re not giving valid values in the necessary `app_id` and `app_key` request headers. Check those values and (re)register or generate a new API key if you need to.

Otherwise, responses from `https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com` API endpoints do contain the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, including the `OPTIONS` response:

```
$ curl -X OPTIONS -i \
   --header "Origin: http://example.com" \
   --header "Access-Control-Request-Headers: app_id, app_key" \
   --header "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" \
   --header "app_id: 023xxxxx" \
   --header "app_key: e6a772cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
   "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/ace/pronunciations"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: app_id
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
Allow: HEAD, OPTIONS, GET
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 01 Aug 2017 22:49:53 GMT
Server: openresty/1.9.7.4
version: v1.1.0-601-g45837e9
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

So if you fix your code to send valid `app_id` and `app_key` request-header values, it should work.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue with oxforddictionaries api, I checked this using postman with same app_id and app_key it's work fine but not works with angular( v5) application.